# Bulb brightness of a simple parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

**Question:** Two bulbs (50W and 80W) are connected in parallel in a simple circuit with a constant voltage supply of 50 volts. Determine which bulb is brighter.

**My attempt:** Since we know that the two bulbs are parallel with each other, the amount of current that passes each bulb is determined by the resistance of each bulb. The resistance of each bulb is $50ohms$ and $31.25ohms$ distinctively. We can then calculate the current that goes through each bulb with the given info. However, this is where my question comes in. What exactly is the determinate for the brightness of the bulbs? Is it just the amount of current? If so, would the bulb with lower resistance always be brighter regardless of whether the bulb in comparison is in parallel or series as long as the voltage for both bulb is identical?

Comment: Do the bulbs have the same voltage rating? Are they the same technology?